# RethinkDb geospatial queries with Java return incorrect values

Tags: java, rethinkdb

I am trying to make a simple RethinkDb query involving the r.point method with java. At first glance, it seemed to work fine. However, executing this method directly from the terminal using the reql syntax return a totally different value. Can anyone understand why is it the case ? Or maybe if they represent the same geospatial coordinates ?

Here is the code I used :

```
    Point geoloc = RethinkDB.r.point(Float.parseFloat(parsedLocation[0]),Float.parseFloat(parsedLocation[1]));

    data.setGeolocation(geoloc);
    db = new Db();
    int reponse = db.putDataInCollection(data); //Simply put the object in the database
```

Which returns this for the geolocation field :

```
"geolocation": {
  "args": [
      {
      "args": [ ],
      "datum": -122 ,
      "optargs": { } ,
      "termType":  "DATUM"
      } ,
      {
      "args": [ ],
      "datum": 88 ,
      "optargs": { } ,
      "termType":  "DATUM"
      }
   ], 
   "optargs": { } ,
   "termType":  "POINT"
   }
```

However, executing the exact same command from the terminal returns :

```
"geolocation": {
   "$reql_type$":  "GEOMETRY" ,
   "coordinates": [
       -122.2 ,
       74.8
       ] ,
   "type":  "Point"
 }
```

Which is definitely not the same thing.

What am I doing wrong ?

Edit : Tried executing the same method using Javascript  and it works perfectly fine. However something seems off in java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still haven't found the cause of the issue by today, but I managed to put in place an alternative solution some time ago, here it is, if someone ever encounter the same problem :

package com.unwheeze.beans;

```
public class GeoBean {

    private String $reql_type$;
    private double coordinates[];
    private String type;


    public GeoBean() {}
    public GeoBean(double[] coordinates) {
        this.$reql_type$ = "GEOMETRY";
        this.coordinates = coordinates;
        this.type = "POINT";
    }

    public String get$reql_type$() {
        return $reql_type$;
    }

    public void set$reql_type$(String $reql_type$) {
        this.$reql_type$ = $reql_type$;
    }

    public double[] getCoordinates() {
        return coordinates;
    }

    public void setCoordinates(double[] coordinates) {
        this.coordinates = coordinates;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }
}
```

I created a simple bean reproducing the fields of the REAL geoJson field in rethinkDb, and I am simply parsing it using Gson before pushing the whole Json object to the database.